# Fluxbox dual screen configuration

Tags: debian, fluxbox, multi-monitor

I recently set up a second monitor for my home computer. Through the use of nvidia-settings, I was able to set up my two monitors. My second monitor is set up as a separate X screen to the right of the main one and Xinerama is enabled. The result it that treats both monitors as one huge monitor, and as such the background and toolbar are stretched across both screens.

I have been unable to find a way to keep my toolbar on one screen and have two separate backgrounds on each monitor. Does anybody know of such a method?

Comment: Disable Xinerama? At my last job I had the setup you're looking for, but you asked three weeks too late. I'm pretty sure it used the NVidia TwinView setting and not Xinerama.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nvidia uses its own "TwinView" technique, are you sure you really use Xinerama? In case you do, give a try w/o it.

**UPD**.: Reading `man fluxbox`:

> ```
>        session.screen0.toolbar.onhead: <integer>
>              For those that use xinerama, users can set this value to the number of the
>              head where they would like to see the slit and toolbar, starting from 1.
>              Setting this to 0 will ignore xinerama information. Default: 0
> ```

Also, AFAIR, Fluxbox would allow for several X Screens running w/o Xinerama/TwinView (you wouldn't be able to move windows across them, though).

BTW, it's accessible with menu: fluxbox menu→configure→toolbar→on head…

Comment: You have solved the toolbar issue. I left Xinerama on (disabling does not allow me to drag windows between monitors). The background issue is still there but I think I should be able to figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: FYI: twinview is xinerama from fluxbox' point of view.  same for the thing ati calls their twinview/xinerama clone

Comment: The issue with TwinView is that my monitors are of different resolutions. Using TwinView creates about 180 pixels of unseeable "dead space" under my second monitor.

Comment: @0nyx, use @-notation, dude. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have used `arandr` (available with apt-get). It creates a script setting the desired monitor configuration, then this script must be called in the fluxbox startup script.